# Java Object format to String Number with Decimals

Tags: java, formatting, format, decimal

so I have an array list of Objects and in it are string numbers. I want to add decimal places to these numbers (8).

```
String value = String.valueOf(accountEntry.get(4));
double amount = Double.valueOf(value);

String formatted = String.format(Locale.GERMANY,"%.8f",amount);
accountEntry.add(formatted);
```

For example `101700000000` should output `1017` but instead it is `101700000000,00000000`
Does anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: What do you think `.8f` mean?

Comment: 8 is the precision and f means that the result is a formatted a decimal number

Comment: why `101700000000` should output `1017`?

Comment: You are formatting.
If all the numbers you are using have these 8 trailing zeroes, convert the string to a number, then divide it by 100,000,000 and then use a number format on the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello try something like this using Regex , this way you can remove all zeros at the end.

```
String value = String.valueOf("101700000000");
double amount = Double.valueOf(value);
String formatted = String.format(Locale.GERMANY,"%d",(long)amount);
formatted = formatted.replaceAll("0+$", "");
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Input :101700000000 ===> Output: 1017

Comment: Hello this is great! But how can I add decimal points to the 8th position. If the number is 12005377705 this will input also 12005377705 and not 120.05377705

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know where the problem is?

Your Input is : 101700000000 and you are formatting  `String.format(Locale.GERMANY,"%.8f",amount);`  In here your output will be `101700000000,00000000`  So for understand this String Format will not transform your input magicaly to 1017. You need to use another algorithm for this problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any suggestions how can I go about this?

Comment: It is simple how many places of decimals do you want to have 4, 6 , etc. After that you make a simple String Split or a Regex